# How to select one unique value in mysql for the first row then show nothing for that value, BUT show all the records?

Tags: mysql

there are 2 mysql table like this

### table 1

> --id-----config_name
>   --1-----OS
>   --2-----Control Panel
>   --3-----Bandwidth

### table 2

> id --    config_id---    config_Option_name ---   Price
>   1--------1-------------Windows 2008--------20.00
>   2--------1-------------CentOs 5----------------0.00
>   3--------2-------------whm/cPanel-----------30.00
>   4--------2-------------Plesk-------------------50.00

---

Now I want to show them like this, ONLY USING MYSQL.

> 1. OS
>      Windows 2008 = 20.00
>      CentOs 5 = 00.00
> 2. Control Panel
>      whm/cPanel= 30.00
>      Plesk = 50.00

IS THIS  POSSIBLE? So now "os" or "control panel" are selected once although if we use group by or join it comes twice.

Using single SQL statement

Comment: What's the reason for using just a SQL query? Just curious.

Comment: **Side note:** Don't do formatting in SQL. SQL isn't about formatting. JOIN the two tables, and format the output in the front end application.

Comment: hi Osiris, 
I just want to know whether there is a way in which back end application can work mostly like front end application. so we just have to print the result in front end application, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use SQL to format output like this. You should do it on a client side.

Anyway here is a query to do it in SQL only ([SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f5a9/27)):

```
select cfgN from
(
   select concat('\t',
                 CONFIG_OPTION_NAME,
                 '=',FORMAT(Price, 2) ) as cfgN, 
                 config_id,
                 t2.ID,
                 CONFIG_OPTION_NAME,
                 Price 
   from Table2 t2
   join Table1 t1 on (t2.config_id=t1.id)

   union all

   select concat(cast(id as char),
                 '. ',CONFIG_NAME) as cfgN, 
          id config_id,
          null ID,
          CONFIG_NAME, 
          null Price 
   from table1 

) t3 order by config_id,id
```

Comment: Hi, This worked.... thanks  a lot man! Just wanted to check whether mysql can have formatting and can return value on some records only or not. But anyway u did it right!